# Mecurial hg push error

Tags: mercurial

I'm new to Mercurial and I was hoping that you guys could help.  I made and committed some changes on the default and dev branch on my local system.  When I ran the "hg push" command, I got the following error.  Do you know what I have to do to fix it? Thank you.

searching for changes
abort: push creates new remote head 6a3192edc4aa!
(merge or see "hg help push" for details about pushing new heads)

==========

Output of hg log:

changeset:   6583:6a3192edc4aa
tag:         tip
parent:      6581:049cddc21e42
parent:      6582:ae83c2445264
user:        user1
date:        Thu Aug 14 15:35:08 2014 -0400
summary:     Merged with dev.

changeset:   6582:ae83c2445264
branch:      dev
parent:      6579:dd7c0641e5cf
parent:      6581:049cddc21e42
user:        user1
date:        Thu Aug 14 09:53:09 2014 -0400
summary:     Merged with default.

changeset:   6581:049cddc21e42
parent:      6577:df050be5e368
user:        deploy
date:        Fri Aug 08 21:07:14 2014 +0000
summary:     Added tag 0.3.343 for changeset df050be5e368

changeset:   6580:f28967065103
parent:      6577:df050be5e368
user:        user1
date:        Thu Aug 14 09:27:44 2014 -0400
summary:     Fixed a timeout bug.

changeset:   6579:dd7c0641e5cf
branch:      dev
user:        user1
date:        Wed Aug 13 09:29:58 2014 -0400
summary:     Fixed a few typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changesets 6580 and 6583 are both on `default` branch, but are both heads. Issue a `hg merge` and you should be good to push.

Comment: Hi Vince, I'm new to Mercurial so I want to make sure that I don't mess this up.  Should I first switch to the default branch by executing "hg update default" and then "hg merge"?

Comment: Yes, that would be wise. And after the merge, commit.